# Convert spark dataframe to Array[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can any tell me how to convert Spark dataframe into Array[String] in scala.

I have used the following.

```
x =df.select(columns.head, columns.tail: _*).collect()
```

The above snippet gives me an Array[Row] and not Array[String]

Comment: `.map { row => row.toString() }` ??

Comment: thank you for the response. That does the work.Can you tell me if we use.map { row => row.toString() .mkString(",")} eliminate the bracket "[" and "]" when we print it out.

Comment: mkString makes a string from an array... This is all Scala knowledge. How would you make an array a sting in Java or Python? My point is, your question/problem is completely outside of Spark

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df.select(columns: _*).collect.map(_.toSeq)
```

Comment: How can we fix that ``columns`` is generating a ``Cannot resolve symbol`` compilation problem?

Answer (score 5):

DataFrame to Array[String]

```
data.collect.map(_.toSeq).flatten
```

You can also use the following

```
data.collect.map(row=>row.getString(0))
```

If you have more columns then it is good to use the last one

```
 data.rdd.map(row=>row.getString(0)).collect
```

Comment: you can replace .map(_.toSeq).flatten to .flatMap(_.toSeq)

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to read the dataset line by line, then you can use the iterator over the dataset:

```
 Dataset<Row>csv=session.read().format("csv").option("sep",",").option("inferSchema",true).option("escape, "\"").option("header", true).option("multiline",true).load(users/abc/....);

for(Iterator<Row> iter = csv.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    String[] item = ((iter.next()).toString().split(",");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by a user named cricket_007.
You can use the following to convert Array[Row] to Array[String] :

```
x =df.select(columns.head, columns.tail: _*).collect().map { row => row.toString() }
```

Thanks,
Bharath

Comment: `collect()` on a DataFrame is often not how you would use it. Rather, you `show()` it

Comment: Hello cricket_007, I don't think show is useful in this case when you want to assign it a variable.

Comment: Not my point... Collecting the dataframe or RDD to a Scala datatype becomes a bottleneck on the driver process. If you just want to display the output, you select, then show it without a collection